# Do some vascular tissue cells have chloroplast?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, chloroplasts

Vascular tissue includes xylem, phloem, parenchyma, and cambium cells. Does photosynthesis occur in some vascular tissue cells? Do some of them have chloroplast?

Vascular tissues are made up of xylem and phloem, each of which are complex tissues (having more than one cell type). So some of their **parenchyma** cells may have chloroplasts.

The bundle-sheath cells are the photosynthetic cells arranged into a tightly packed sheath around the vein of a leaf. It forms a protective covering on leaf vein, and consist of one or more cell layers, usually **parenchyma**.

I am not sure whether these two "parenchyma"s are the same or not.
Are the bundle sheath cells vascular tissue cells?

Comment: What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for more information.

Comment: @MattDMo ok, I added something :)